# showMessageDialog won't close in game

Tags: java

In my game you are supposed to gain points when you click moving ovals and lose points if you miss them. When a point is gained a message Dialog pops up to say how many points you have. I can't close it because it counts my click as a missed click. It decreases points until the game ends.

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    while (lives > 0) {
        if (oval1.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()) || oval2.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())){
            lives = lives + y;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, lives + " points");
        }
        else {
            lives = lives - y;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, lives + " points");
        }

        if (lives == -1)
            Input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Would you like to reset?");
        if (Input.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
            lives = 3;
        continue;
```

Comment: What have you tried to address it? Have you tried stopping event propagation?

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mcve], so that we can provide better help, as is, we cannot provide much help. Please take the [tour] and read the [help], specially the section on [ask] then come back [edit] your question and post a proper minimal example (this is not your whole program, but rather a new one that isolates the problem in the minimum amount of lines, yet it's still complete enough that we can copy-paste it into our IDE's with little to no (preferably) modification.

Answer (score -1):

You can use make use of `Thread.sleep()` and can disappear the dialog automatically, after a while.

**Code:**

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
    while (lives > 0) {
        if (oval1.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()) || oval2.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
        {
            lives = lives + y;
            showLives();
        }
        else 
        {
            lives = lives - y;
            showLives();
        }

        if (lives == -1)
            Input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Would you like to reset?");
        if (Input.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
            lives = 3;
        continue;
    }
}

public void showLives()
{
    JOptionPane message = new JOptionPane("Points: " + lives, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, null, new Object[]{});  //no buttons will be created
    final JDialog dialog = message.createDialog("Information");
    new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1500);  // this controls for how long you want the dialog to appear
                        dialog.dispose();
                    }
                    catch ( Throwable t )
                    {}
                }
            }).start();
  dialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

**Note:** I have made `showLives()` each time you call this method it will pop up the `lives` and will disappear. So, no need to click to close.

Comment: Dear down voter, what is the problem with my code ? So that i can fix it !

Comment: I'm getting an error saying                                                                                                                      - JmessageionPane cannot be resolved to a variable
- JmessageionPane cannot be resolved to a type

   is there an import statement or something required to use it?

Comment: @quasar81 sorry it was a typo off course there is no class like that ... I have updated my answer it'll work like a charm ... do tell me if it helped you or not !

Comment: i'm still getting an error that says DEFAULT_messageION cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: @quasar81i have updated the code ... use the updated version, you are using the previous one.

Comment: That was the updated code. I got an alternate method from my teacher who was gone though, so I’m fine now.